# Swift af_setImage value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm using a custom class to have round images in my project, now i'm adding an image

```
 @IBOutlet weak var myImage: RoundImage!
```

in a viewController but i get an error in this function

```
 func update(place:QPlace) {
        myLabel.text = place.getDescription()
        myImage.image = nil

        if let url = place.photos?.first?.getPhotoURL(maxWidth: maxWidht) {
            myImage.af_setImage(withURL: url)
        }
    }
```

that said to me: "Value of type 'RoundImage' has no member 'af_setImage'"

How can i solve it? (i know that is not a new question here on stack overflow but i didn't find a specific answer to my problem)

Comment: af_setImage is a function declared in UIImageView extension in AlamofireImage library. Are you sure you've added AlamofireImage lib to your project?

Comment: @AuRis oh you are right, done, thank you!

Comment: My previous comment assumes that your RoundImage is a subclass of UIImageView. On that note, you'll help yourself if you name that class RoundImageView and your variable myImageView, in that way you'll avoid confusion between UIImage and UIImageView types.

Comment: Glad you solved it.